# How to create a json when I only know its jsonPath

Tags: java, json

I have some jsonPath infomation like below:

```
"syncData": {
        "$.name": "haha",
        "$.accountId": "1848",
        "$.probability": 9,
        "$.dealInfoVo.amount": "1000",
        "$.description": "11144",
        "$.owners[0].ownerUserId": "999",
        "$.owners[0].isPrimary": "true",
        "$.expectedCloseTime": 1543680000000,
      }
```

and How can I create the json using those jsonPath infomation?
the expected json like this:

```
{
    "name":"haha",
    "accountId":"1848",
    "probability":"9",
    "dealInfoVO":{
        "amount":"1000"
    },
    "description":"11144",
    "owners":[
        {
            "ownerUserId":"999",
            "isPrimary":"true"
        }
    ],
    "expectedCloseTime":1543680000000
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Andreas I tried to recursive create JsonObject by analysis path. for example : I read the path from beginning to end, every time I met a "."
  then I find the field,if not founded, I create a subJsonObject and put its reference into the parent Object, but the difficulty is the array, it's so complex.

Comment: You could parse the array by "[" and "]" and the position in the array by the number between the two square bracket. If it is an array, the array identifier will always be the last 3 characters of that particular path segment. Please include in the question your attempt so far